# Closing a div - javascript not wokring

Tags: javascript

Im trying to add in a close button for my div. It opens all ok but doesnt close and I cant fathom why ...

The code is here

```js
window.onload = function display() {
  document.getElementById("advert").style.display = "block";
}



function close() {
  document.getElementById("advert").style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<div id="advert">
  <div class="advert-content">
    <button class="Close" onclick="close()">&times;</button>
    <p>Content is here</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can't use "close()" as a function name, it seems to be reserved (which makes kind of sense). Just use another name.

```js
window.onload = function display() {
  document.getElementById("advert").style.display = "block";
}



function xclose() {
  document.getElementById("advert").style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<div id="advert">
  <div class="advert-content">
    <button class="Close" onclick="xclose()">&times;</button>
    <p>Content is here</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: that works! thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

[`Window.close()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close) is a reserved word in JavaScript.

> The `Window.close()` method closes the current window, or the window on which it was called.

When you use that name as your function name, that function is actually overridden by [`Window.close()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close) and nothing happens.

Change your function name from `close` to some other name.

```js
window.onload = function display() {
  document.getElementById("advert").style.display = "block";
}


function closeDiv() {
  document.getElementById("advert").style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<div id="advert">
  <div class="advert-content">
    <button class="Close" onclick="closeDiv()">&times;</button>
    <p>Content is here</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers have mentioned `close` is a reserved word, but that only seems to apply to inline JS. You can move the code for the event listener outside of the HTML and still use `close` as your function name. As an added benefit not-including JS in your HTML is considered good practice.

```js
const button = document.querySelector('.close');
button.addEventListener('click', close, false);

function close() {
  document.getElementById("advert").style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<div id="advert">
  <div class="advert-content">
    <button class="close">&times;</button>
    <p>Content is here</p>
  </div>
</div>
```